# Javascript - Multiple XmlHttpRequests, and associating with them target divs

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, closures

I have a page with multiple XmlHttpRequest calls, and I know which connection I would like to output to which div.

Is there a way I can reuse the code of the function somehow passing the divname I'd like the output to be written to.

right now, I'm literally duplicating the functions 6 times over!

Comment: Yes, easily done with the lexical scope/closure concept. It'd be better if you showed the code of 2 of your requests for a faster and more objective refactoring.

Comment: You could make a JSON object sever side where the key is for query selector (like #myDiv) and value is the content. {"#myDiv":"text...",".myClass":"other text..."}. On client side Json.parse the responseText and walk through with for in.

Answer (score 3):

Of course you can.

If you're trying to do the exact same thing with 6 different divs, but using 6 different calls with 6 different responses, then make a function which takes a div, and use that function 6 times...

```
var doSomethingAJAX = function (el, url) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", url, true);
    xhr.onload = function () { el.appendChild(document.createTextNode(xhr.responseText)); };
    xhr.onerror = function () { /* ... */ };
    xhr.send();
};

doSomethingAJAX(document.getElementById("div1"), "http://example.com/json1.json");
doSomethingAJAX(document.getElementById("div2"), "http://example.com/json2.json");
```

There are more-generalized ways to do this, but I'm not going to suggest that you make an AJAX framework, if you're trying to solve for 6 `<div>`s.

The point is, whatever work it is that you're repeating, figure out how to turn that into a function (or two functions, or three), and call that function, passing in only the parts that change.

If this is way off, then update your question with examples, and we can figure something out.